# ZXing.Net.Mobile buttonScan.Click function arguments, what are they for?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, zxing

What exactly are both of the arguments `sender` and `e` used for?

```
   buttonScan.Click += (sender, e) => {
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
        var result = await scanner.Scan();

        if (result != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
    };
```

Why can't I call this function with no arguments?

Comment: `sender` is, well, the *sender* of the event. In this case, most likely the `buttonScan` control. And `e` is "everything else"; kidding. No, `e` is the [EventArg(ument)s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.eventargs.aspx) parameter. `Action<object, EventArgs>` is the standard [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate.

Comment: If you're confused about the `(sender, e) => { [...] }` syntax, that's a so called [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions), which is basically a shorthand method definition. You *could* have a separate method `void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) { [...] }` defined somewhere else instead and use `buttonScan.Click += HandleClick;`. Some people prefer one over the other, but in the end, it doesn't really matter.